# "User Filter" and "Branch Filter" equivalent for Webhooks in BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket, webhooks, githooks, bitbucket-pipelines, git-webhooks

We are trying to migrate from `Hooks` to `Webhooks` on 'BitBucket' and can't find a way to specify the *Branch Filter* and *User Filter*.

While using `Hooks`, we just need to specify the regex values as in the image below to notify a job to trigger for 'Development' branch and to ignore the commits by the user 'default_user'. Is there a way to achieve the same result with `Webhooks`?

[image]